# I don't understand this crash

Tags: c

This is my code for solving the problem "Students Marks Sum" in Hackerrank:
(Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/students-marks-sum/problem?)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Complete the following function.

int marks_summation(int* marks, int number_of_students, char gender) {
    int result = 0;
    
  switch (gender){
      case 'b':
        while(marks != NULL){
            result += (*marks);
            marks += 2;
        }
      case 'g':
        ++marks;
        while(marks != NULL){
            result += (*marks);
            marks += 2;
        }
        break;
  }
  
  return result;
}

int main() {
    int number_of_students;
    char gender;
    int sum;
  
    scanf("%d", &number_of_students);
    int *marks = (int *) malloc(number_of_students * sizeof (int));
 
    for (int student = 0; student < number_of_students; student++) {
        scanf("%d", (marks + student));
    }
    
    scanf(" %c", &gender);
    sum = marks_summation(marks, number_of_students, gender);
    printf("%d", sum);
    free(marks);
 
    return 0;
}
```

When I move this code into an IDE (in my situation, it's DEV C/C++), it was crashed when my debug ran into my function `marks_summation`.

Error in line:

```
result += (*marks);
```

Comment: Please try to make a more helpful question title that describes your specific problem.

Comment: In switch block, `marks` will not be NULL after you have iterated through all students. In that case loop will not exit and you may access some memory that you have not allocated. That is undefined behavior. you should use `number_of_students` parameter for the loop instead

Comment: `while(marks != NULL)`. How do you expect `mark` to become NULL when the only operation to change `marks` is increment?

Comment: Did you skip the `break;` intentionally in your `case ' b':`? If so please explain.

Comment: Avoid using challenge sites to learn to program. The blanket code they provide is horrible and littered with bad programming practices. You can never use an input function correctly (much less `scanf()`) unless you **check the return** BEFORE you attempt to use the value filled to determine if the input succeeded or failed. You cannot allocate correctly unless you check the allocation succeeded or failed, end on and on... So be careful you don't pick up bad coding habits from those sites. `while(marks != NULL)` -- you never set a sentinel `NULL`, so this fails. Loop `number_of_students` times

Comment: Side node: `scanf("%d", (marks + student));`: this is correct, but not very readable. You should rather write: `scanf("%d", &marks[student]);`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your assumption that if you move out of the range of dynamically allocated memory the pointer value will change to `NULL`:

```
    while(marks != NULL){
        result += (*marks);
        marks += 2;
    }
```

There are a number of approaches you can pick to iterate over such array.

You can calculate the memory address that will no longer be valid to read and check at each iteration if your pointer is smaller than it:

```
int marks_summation(int* marks, int number_of_students, char gender) {
    int result = 0;
    int* marksEnd = marks + number_of_students;
    
    switch (gender){
      case 'b':
        while(marks < marksEnd){
            result += (*marks);
            marks += 2;
        }
      case 'g':
        ++marks;
        while(marks < marksEnd){
            result += (*marks);
            marks += 2;
        }
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Well, I think I've a lot of things to learn.